# Numpy - n largest values by column by axis 0 in 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that takes a 2D or 3D numpy array and it returns the n highest values from each column. The function produces the intended results. but it is a bit convoluted.

```
def scoring(scores: np.ndarray, n_slots: int) -> np.ndarray:
    """Calculates bestball scoring for n_slots
    
    Args:
        scores (np.ndarray): the 2D array of scores
        n_slots (int): the number of scores who count

    Returns:
        np.ndarray of shape 1, scores.shape[1]

    """
    def _scoring(scores, n_slots):
        if n_slots == 1:
            return scores.max(axis=0)
        index_array = np.argpartition(-scores, kth=1, axis=0)
        return np.take_along_axis(scores, index_array[0:n_slots], axis=0)

    if scores.ndim == 2:
        return _scoring(scores, n_slots)
    elif scores.ndim == 3:
        return np.array([_scoring(s, n_slots) for s in scores])

>>> scores = np.array([[1, 3, 5], [4, 6, 1], [3, 9, 0]])
>>> scoring(scores, 2)
array([[4, 9, 5],
       [3, 6, 1]])

>>> scores = np.array([[[1, 3, 5], [4, 6, 1], [3, 9, 0]], [[10, 3, 5], [41, 6, 1], [3, 9, 20]]])
>>> scoring(scores, 2)
array([[[ 4,  9,  5],
        [ 3,  6,  1]],

       [[41,  9, 20],
        [10,  6,  5]]])
```

I'm wondering if there is way to handle both 2D and 3D score arrays without resorting to calling a 2D function in a list comprehension, as I've done in the example above.

Comment: Not sure if you've noticed but I've just edited the answer below with a one-liner ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your two examples we are working on the *before-last* axis (not necessarily the *2nd* axis - which is only true for the former example, not for the latter).

For a general implementation this axis is given to us by:

```
>>> axis = x.ndim - k
```

I've taken the liberty to rename `n_slots` as `k`.

What about using `numpy.sort` on `axis`:

```
>>> res = -np.sort(-x, axis=axis)
```

Then dynamically taking the necessary elements with [`np.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html):

```
>>> res.take(np.arange(k), axis=axis)
```

---

Alternatively, you can get away without without having to infer the *before-last* axis by using `axis=-2` and an indexing trick:

```
>>> -np.sort(-x, -2)[..., :k, :]
```

This basically makes it a one-liner:

```
>>> def topk(x,  k):
...    return -np.sort(-x, -2)[..., :k, :]
```

---

```
>>> topk(np.array([[1, 3, 5], 
                   [4, 6, 1], 
                   [3, 9, 0]]), k=2)
array([[4, 9, 5],
       [3, 6, 1]])

>>> topk(np.array([[[1, 3, 5], 
                    [4, 6, 1], 
                    [3, 9, 0]], 
                   [[10, 3, 5], 
                    [41, 6, 1], 
                    [3, 9, 20]]]), k=2)
array([[[ 4,  9,  5],
        [ 3,  6,  1]],

       [[41,  9, 20],
        [10,  6,  5]]])
```